# Manual folding in vim

Tags: vim, line, vi, folding, manual

When manual folding is active, I fold lines 21-23 in the following code,

```
19         while (fgets(line, LINESIZE, fp)) {
20                 line[strlen(line)-1] = '\0';
21                 if (regexec(&reg, line, 0, NULL, 0) == REG_NOMATCH) {
22                         return -1*lineno; 
23                 }
24
25
26                 lineno++;
27         }
```

but after sometime I add some another lines (for example 2 lines) between lines 21-23. But when I press fore example za command, 5 lines are folded/unfolded.

My question is, in manual folding, doed number of folded lines can be changhed?

Thank you

Comment: How did you create that manual fold?

Comment: set foldmethod=manual

Comment: That's not how you create manual folds.

Comment: So, can you explain more? Thank you

Comment: Well, that command enables manual folding but it doesn't create folds. The method is "manual" so you create folds manually, with the relevant commands under `:help folding`. What I'm asking you is to tell us which ones you used and how.

Comment: I see, I enter in command line  "21,23 fold"